# Remove/Delete build parameters once used

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have some multi-branch pipeline jobs which are set up via Jenkinsfiles.
When we were setting up the jobs, we used build parameters to parameterize the build.

Now this is not relevant anymore, so we removed the parameters from the Jenkinsfile.
But they are still visible via the UI and the *“build”* button is still a *“build with parameters”* button.

The configuration of each branch only lists the parameters.
But they cannot be deleted and the *“this build is parameterized”* checkbox is activated but greyed out.

Is there any way to remove these old parameters?

THX :-)